# List.Count always returns 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, list

I'm creating a public static `List<>` of variables (from `MySQL` query) but the `List`'s `Count` always returns `0`! I've tried everything so far but no success. Here is my code:

```
public static List<string> GetHashedVars(string ID)
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    MySqlConnection conn;
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    MySqlDataReader reader;
    string connString, queryStr = "";
    connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GameserverConnString"].ToString();
    using (conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
    {
        //The query for execution
        queryStr = "SELECT * FROM account.account WHERE id_hashed=?hid LIMIT 1";
        //Open the connection to the database
        conn.Open();
        //execute command
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?hid", ID);
        using (reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            //Loop through results
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                lst.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("id_hashed")));
                lst.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("login_hashed")));
                lst.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("webcode_hashed")));
                lst.Add(Encryption.CipherEncryption(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("status")).Trim()));
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
    queryStr = "";
    reader = null;
    cmd = null;
    conn = null;
    connString = "";
    return lst;
}
```

Comment: Have you debug it first? Are you getting connected to the database?

Comment: Have you debugged? At the line where you are reading and adding to the list can you see if it actually adds anything in?

Comment: Does the query return any rows

Comment: Set breaking point and use debugging tool to inspect the variables.You could easily find where you went wrong.

Comment: Yes I did. The connection to the database is successful because I have the exact same function (different but same structure) twice! I even got a label in the `.ASPX` to display the total `Count` of items (was 0). I don't know what else can I try it just keeps throwing me `Index out of range` exceptions to this particular one...

Comment: List.Count isn't broken. *Did you really debug your code*? Were there any results? Did your loop run? Did all of the `lst.Add` lines execute correctly or was there an error? Do you check the `lst` variable that is returned here or some other variable by mistake? Or is there some `catch{}` kind of code that hides exceptions?

Comment: Put breakpoints inside the reader loop and ensure that you do get results. If `lst` has no elements at the end of the method, that's because nothing was added to it

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using named parameters but do not set your parameters correctly.

`?` is used for non named parameters and `@` are used for named parameters. Since  the database connector you are using does not support `non named parameters` you have to follow the convention using the `@` in your query. This will set the parameters by name rather than by index.

```
queryStr = "SELECT * FROM account.account WHERE id_hashed=@hid LIMIT 1";
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hid", ID);
```

Explanation from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> The Microsoft .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server does not
>   support the question mark (?) placeholder for passing parameters to a
>   SQL Statement or a stored procedure called by a command of
>   CommandType.Text. In this case, named parameters must be used.

Comment: `@` is for SQL and `?` is for MySQL I think. Anyway I solved it I think it was bad hashing format in the records. Thank you so much for your help guys.